# Uploading/integrating custom user registration page

Tags: php, users, user-registration

I'm fairly new to Wordpress.

I'm trying to replace my existing user registration page with a registration page I created that is using PHP and connect to a MySQL database that I created for users. I uploaded the database using the PHPMyadmin plugin dashboard. My question is if there is any "explain it like I'm 5" documentation on uploading my own login pages in order to connect the fields to my database that I uploaded. I've searched and can't find anything that provides basic instructions.

Tried:
-Searching hosting docs
-Searching Youtube videos
-Searching this forum - some questions/answers are close, but not exact.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to bypass WordPress's user registration and logins entirely, and that would be why there's no documentation on doing so. It is possible to use outside authentication such as single sign-on to log people in using external accounts, but even then those users are using WordPress accounts once logged in. It's inadvisable to try to have users log in using something else completely and try to manage the cookies on your own outside of WordPress - if that's really what you need WP may not bring you much benefit.

Comment: Thank you. I created a website to allow people to subscribe. I really don't have a preference of how it's done. I just need the fields customized and a way to connect it to my database.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on how to use the integrated hooks and filters to manipulate wp login. Just dig after these keywords, e.g. login hooks and filters wordpress.

Comment: What I actually need is a replacement for Adminer WP Database Plugin which was discontinued a couple of months ago. With that plugin I just need to specify my DB name in settings. There should be no coding involved. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TE7dLY_VjQ. I looked in vain for a replacment.

Comment: Adminer was discontinued for major security risks, but you should be able to make adjustments in the database through phpMyAdmin. Check with your host to see if that's available.

Comment: Thanks all. After researching extensively the plugin "Participants Database" will give me the functionality I meed.